# Selecting 1 record from one table and 0.n from another

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have 2 tables (clients and client_forms). The client is always a single instance (as it relates to a single person, but they fill in a form annually (1 - 0.n). I need a MySQL statement that selects all forms for each client, but I'm not sure how to do this. Would it use some kind of nested query?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you read into the [`JOIN` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html). Essentially you'll have to write

```
SELECT *
FROM clients
[LEFT OUTER] JOIN client_forms ON [put the join condition here]
```

I'm not sure if you need this to be a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (always returns at least one record per client), or an `INNER JOIN` (returns one record per client and form)

Comment: Which type of join makes a 1-0.n join?

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN, as Lukas put in his query.

Comment: You probably want to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, as you probably always want to have at least one resulting record per client. You'll find more information in the manual

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  *
from
  clients
  join clent_forms on client_forms.client_id=clients.client_id
```

will return all the clients with all their forms - assuming that there is a `client_id` column in both tables identifying the client. It WON'T return clients that have no forms.

If you want also clients without forms you need an `outer` join:

```
select
  *
from
  clients
  left outer join clent_forms on client_forms.client_id=clients.client_id
```